# Where can i download sample siebel CRM application to practice automation testing

Tags: testing, automated-tests, crm, siebel

I want to create a POC of automation testing for Siebel CRM application.
Can anybody suggest any sample CRM application or refere a place from where i can download Siebel application.

Also it will be helpful if anybody recommend  any automation testing tool to perform automation testing on siebel CRM based application.

Thanks,
Bibek

Answer (score 2):

the fastest option is to use the Siebel 20.x Sample images on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure. This will give you a current 20.x Siebel Server instance with the sample (Oracle) database. https://cloudmarketplace.oracle.com/marketplace/en_US/listing/75325155

Running the Jenkins-driven setup completes in approximately 40 minutes. Compared to installing everything on your own which takes 1 day at minimum (if you know what you are doing).

Test Automation is built in since Siebel IP 17, allowing in-client recording as well as unit and batch playback.

(see Test Automation Guide in Siebel Bookshelf https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F26413_05/books/TestGuide/index.html )

@lex